# An identity between the d'Alembertian and the covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

Suppose $f$ is function which depends on $\phi$, $f = f(\phi)$; and $\phi$ is a scalar field. We define
$$\square \equiv g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu$$ and $$\nabla_\mu f(\phi) \equiv  f_{;\nu}$$
**Is this expression below correct?**

**$$ -f_{;\mu\nu} + \square f g_{\mu\nu} = 0  $$**

I think it is correct since
$$  \nabla_\nu(\nabla_\mu f) =  f_{;\mu\nu} $$ and
$$(g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu f) g_{\mu\nu} = \square f g_{\mu\nu} = (\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu f)g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} =\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu f$$
but I doubt it, I need another point of view.

ps: for further, you can check arXiv:2009.11827. I try to prove equation (18).

Comment: It is not correct. In your last line, you have mixed dummy indices (i.e. indices which are being summed over) with free indices. You should write $(g^{\alpha\beta} \nabla_\alpha \nabla_\beta f) g_{\mu\nu}$. Immediately it is possible to see that no simplification is possible.

Comment: thank you, Prahar. I appreciate it

Comment: A counter-example is Minkowski space with $f = \frac{1}{2} (x^0)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to prove eq (18) in 2009.11827. That has nothing to do with the identity you are asking about in the question (which is completely incorrect, btw). To derive (18) in the ref. we simply need to vary the action w.r.t. the metric ($G_4$ is a function only of $\varphi$)
$$
\delta \int \sqrt{-g} G_4 R = \int \left[ \delta  \sqrt{-g} G_4R + \sqrt{-g} G_4\delta  R \right]
$$
Next, we use
$$
\delta \sqrt{-g} = - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} , \qquad \delta R = R_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} - \delta g^{\mu\nu}{}_{;\mu\nu} + g_{\mu\nu} \Box \delta g^{\mu\nu} 
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\delta \int \sqrt{-g} G_4R &= \int \sqrt{-g}  \left[ - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}  G_4R +  G_4 R_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} - G_4 \delta g^{\mu\nu}{}_{;\mu\nu} + G_4 g_{\mu\nu} \Box \delta g^{\mu\nu}  \right]\\
&= \int \sqrt{-g}  \left[ G_4 E_{\mu\nu} - G_{4;\mu\nu}  + g_{\mu\nu}  \Box G_4 \right] \delta g^{\mu\nu} 
\end{align}
Thus, the equations of motion are
$$
{\cal E}_{\mu\nu}^{(4)} = G_4 E_{\mu\nu} - G_{4;\mu\nu}  + g_{\mu\nu}  \Box G_4
$$
The identity in the question is not correct and is also not relevant to the calculation.

Comment: Actually, I did the same way what you write above, but I simply didn't know that delta R has a form like that. I find only the first term (which contained Einstein tensor) so that I assumed the last two-term must be zero (that's why I wrote "I doubt it").

But, thank you very much. It is really helpful.

Comment: Given that you are reading the paper you mentioned, it seems that you should be able to derive $\delta R$. You shouldn't need to remember or know it. It would be good for you if you go through that derivation (for your own satisfaction).

Comment: @Adika if you find an answer helpful accept the answer! This is indeed the derivation you're looking for!

Comment: yeah, I should derive $\delta R$ by myself; for this case, I just using it (and don't really understand the derivation in the book). Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @ApolloRa Sorry. I am new at this, so I don't really know the rules. thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 3):

This expression:

$$(g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu f) g_{\mu\nu} = \square f g_{\mu\nu} = (\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu f)g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} =\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu f,$$

is wrong. This does not hold. The Box operator is a scalar quantity. It is defined as:

$$\Box = g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}$$

and for a four dimensional diagonal metric this is:

$$\Box = g^{tt}\nabla_{t}\nabla_{t} + g^{xx}\nabla_{x}\nabla_{x} + g^{yy}\nabla_{y}\nabla_{y} + g^{zz}\nabla_{z}\nabla_{z}$$

You abused notation and thus you're not able to see this but the indices for the box term $\mu, \nu$ denote summation (dummy indices) while the indices for the metric denote components (free indices). A more correct way do write it would be:

$$\Box f g_{\mu\nu} =  (g^{\alpha\beta}\nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\beta} f) g_{\mu\nu} $$

Also $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu} =d$ where $d$ is the dimensionality of spacetime for a diagonal metric. I hope this helps.

Comment: You're assuming here that the metric is diagonal, which it may not be.

Comment: Oh you're right but it does not matter, ithink i've made my point.

Comment: I corrected it though.

Comment: yeah, I know your point. But, in the paper I read, it looks like the expression I wrote above must be true except my proving was wrong.

Comment: Could you give a reference? Add it in the question.

Comment: done. I try to prove eq. 18, but I found it hard to prove

Answer (score -1):

Your expression is correct if you're using a derivative that is [compatible with the metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_connection#Riemannian_connection), so if $\nabla_\mu g_{\rho\sigma}=0$, otherwise the d'Alembertian would bring other terms too.

**Edit:** The reason why I think this is correct is

$\Box f g_{\rho\sigma}=g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu f g_{\rho\sigma}=\nabla^\nu\nabla_\nu f g_{\rho\sigma}$
$f_{,\rho\sigma}=\nabla_\rho\nabla_\sigma f =\nabla^\rho\nabla_\rho f g_{\rho\sigma}=\nabla^\nu\nabla_\nu f g_{\rho\nu}g^{\rho\nu}g_{\rho\sigma}=\nabla^\nu\nabla_\nu f g_{\rho\sigma}$

I may be wrong, as @Prahar says, but I can't see where.

Comment: thank you, Mauro.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Kindly edit or delete.